# MYSQL database updation with json data

Tags: html, mysql, json, ajax, forms

I have to update multiple rows in the mysql database using HTML form select box in the front end. The data is retrieved from the database using JSON and AJAX successfully. Could anyone tell me on how to do the updation?

Comment: could you please provide your actual requirement or sample?

Comment: Hey! I have to obtain values from the database in JSON format which I have done successfully using ajax. I have displayed the JSON data using an HTML form, where a certain value can be changed. If that value is changed how do I update it in the database? I tried using form action but the submit button doesn't redirect to the required page. Could you tell me about how I should proceed?

Comment: you should set action and method for form and also button type as submit, I can't say more without seeing your code